# './' and '/' giving different result in JavaScript src reference

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, frontend

My app created using react and express works all okay if I refence script source inside the index.html with '/' in the beginning instead of './'
For example, './something.js'under script source doesn't work while '/something.js' works perfectly
The react build bundle is being used as source of static files for my app.
 Are './' and '/' the same?